# Tools to ease Monero source code pull request

Tags: github, source-code-documentation, git

After seeing this [meta question](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/mixin-vs-ring-size) I thought I would research the difficulty of submitting a pull request to replace `mixin` with `ring size` everywhere it is found in Monero source code.

Although I believe I am capable of doing this manually, there are so many uses of the term in [multiple repositories](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mixin) that it might take me a long time.

Are there any GitHub tools that can help me find and replace every instance of `mixin` with `ring size` automatically so that I don't have to spend hours on the task?

Comment: Do NOT do that, or your PR will be rejected. mixin and ring size are NOT synonymous, and doing this will break monero. If it was so simple, a simple sed script would have done it already.

Comment: I appreciate the proactiveness but it's very dangerous to do things like this automatically. As said above, if it was so simple one script could do it. There isn't urgency in doing this, as all we really 'have' to do is change what the user sees, and that's it. Transfer command will also have to be modified to deal with the difference (ring size = mixin + 1). Doesn't mean that all instances of the term (in the code) must be replaced immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the comments from user36303 and JollyMort see [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3502/136) to my recent question about the difference between ring size and mixin. The distinction is clarified below:

> Ring size = 'mixin' (number of foreign outputs) + 1 (your output)

I agree with the advice above that this task is not urgent and should be left to someone very familiar with the codebase. No find/replace script or other automated tool is appropriate here.